# Webpack bundles are not found

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I had a project running (and working) with webpack 3.10.0 and I have upgraded it to the last webpack release (4.8.3).

To do this I had to update my webpack config file, but I'm having a problem with my bundles. When the browser requests them, they aren't sent.

My previous webpack config file is:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['./client/Client.jsx'],
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'react-router-dom', 'react-router-bootstrap', 'isomorphic-fetch', 'babel-polyfill'],
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/static`,
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.bundle.js' }),
    new Visualizer(),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 8000, // convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
            name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
          },
        }],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8000,
    contentBase: 'static',
    proxy: {
      '*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
      },
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
    https: true,
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

The new one is:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

const WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './client/Client.jsx',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',
      minSize: 30000,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 5,
      maxInitialRequests: 3,
      automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
      name: true,
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
  },

  plugins: [
    // new WriteFilePlugin(),
    new Visualizer(),
    // new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
  //  new UglifyJsPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 8000, // convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
            name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
          },
        }],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8000,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
    proxy: {
      '*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
      },
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
    https: true,
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

The html template that receives the contents is:

```
export default function template(body) {
  return `<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html  lang='pt'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MERN App</title>
    <script src="/bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script async src="/react.production.min.js"></script>

    <script async src="/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <script async src="/bootstrap/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SaudeBemEstar.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="contents">${body}</div>
    <!-- this is where our component will appear By separating html from jsx the transformation of jsx to js stops happening during runtime-->
    <script async type = 'text/javascript'>
        if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
          console.log('Service worker not supported');
        }
        else {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
          .then(function() {
            console.log('Registered');
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Registration failed:', error);
          });
        }

    </script>

    <script src="/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/app.bundle.js"></script>

  </body>
  </html>
  `;
}
```

I have also used the WriteFilePlugin to see if the bundles are created correctly and in the right folder and everything is ok. When I do this the bundles are loaded correctly.

There are also no errors or warnings in the console, except for warnings related to the bundles size.

All the static files are being loaded, the only thing that isn't loaded are the bundles.

I have also set output.publicPath to other values and then changed the src attribute in the script tag, but the problem still happened.

**Edit:** in case someone runs into the same problem, I have found [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/24) that describes the problem. This isn't an ideal solution, but for now I am using the solution provided by @reyou